# What dose mean additional stipulation for add, equals, hashcode method of Set interface in java

Tags: java, collections, set, effective-java

In Effective Java 3/E Item 41, Marker Annotation

I saw the below sentence

> Arguably, the Set interface is just such a restricted marker interface. It is applicable only to Collection subtypes, but it adds no methods beyond those defined by Collection. It is not generally considered to be a marker interface because it refines the contracts of several Collection methods, including add, equals, and hashCode.

and then i found the below sentence from [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

> The Set interface places additional stipulations, beyond those inherited from the Collection interface, on the contracts of all constructors and on the contracts of the add, equals and hashCode methods. Declarations for other inherited methods are also included here for convenience. (The specifications accompanying these declarations have been tailored to the Set interface, but they do not contain any additional stipulations.)

so.. in case of add method,
is 'additional stipulation' mean that set implementations have to implement add method to avoid contain duplicate element?

if is right,
then what is 'additional stipulation' of equals and hashcode?

Comment: For hashcode, it says that the hashcode must be the sum of the hashcodes of all the elements of the set. For equals, the Collections interface doesn't add any additional constraints than Object does, but the Set interface requires that the other object is a set and that all objects in the other set are contained in this set.